# Varnish 4 -> how can i load content into Varnish using Curl

Tags: php, curl, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have 8 servers caching content from an API, the issue is keeping them at sync.

So i was wondering the same way we can http PURGE via curl, can i do the same to call each cache server and make it cache a specific url?

i tried doing it using curl and testing with postman at the same time, but seems to see it as different requests.

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please post how you run curl and your VCL.

Comment: Hi Daniel,Im using :
curl --verbose --header 'Host:<domain>' 'http://<serverIP>/api/blockbuster/menu'

Comment: If you cannot post complete VCL, you can at least post your ```vcl_hash```. This is likely where the culprit is.

Comment: vcl 4.0;
backend default {.host = "xxx.xx.xxx.xx";.port = "80";}
 backend CMS_prod {
     
     .host = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
     .port = "80";
     .first_byte_timeout = 300s;
 }

Comment: sub vcl_recv {
   
    


    
    
 if (req.http.host == "<domain>") {
        #You will need the following line only if your backend has multiple virtual host names
        set req.backend_hint = CMS_prod;
        if (req.url ~ "availability=now") 
        {
               return (pass);
      }else{
      return (hash);
        }

  return (hash);
    }


   }

Comment: sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
    if (bereq.url ~ "/api/") 
 {
  unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        unset beresp.http.cookie;
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 36h;
       
 }
 

    set beresp.ttl = 36h;
    set beresp.grace = 36h;
    return (deliver);
}

Comment: sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
     unset resp.http.Via;  
    #unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Server;
}

sub vcl_backend_error {
    set beresp.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    synthetic( {"errors due to backend fetch"} );
    return (deliver);
}

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to upload files to here, but i don't have a VCL_hash either :-(